# Finding a point within a triangle using barycentric coordinates

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Given a triangle ABC how do I find the position of point D using barycentric coordinates?

Comment: Have you looked at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Barycentric_coordinates_on_triangles)?  They have three barycentric coordinates that add to $1$ for each point, not two.  Presumably the third is $0$, but in what order?

Comment: What 3 points (assuming we're in the plane) are the barycentric coordinates in respect to?

Comment: @GPerez my mistake with the question...the three points( ABC ) form a triangle ... I want to find the position of the fourth point which is at the barycenter of the triangle...i've figured out one method i will post above but it only finds the point at the barycenter...won't work for other barycentric coordinates...

Comment: Isn't it just $(\frac13,\frac13,\frac13)$ in reference $\{A,B,C\}$? If you're allowed to choose the barycentric system of reference it turns out to be simple, though I presume you mean using one they already give you? In other words, if $D$ is the barycenter, then $D=\frac13 A + \frac13 B + \frac13 C$

Comment: @GPerez yes ...

Comment: Yes to which part? My answer is right or you have to use a reference they give you? (In this case which one?)

Comment: @GPerez your answer is right ...

Answer (score 1):

I found a link  [here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-pinpoint-the-center-of-a-triangle.html) that describes a method for computing the position of a point that lies at the barycenter of a triangle ... it does not, however, provide a method for computing the position of a point at a specified barycentric coordinate...